# Python custom types not recognised

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Ok so I'm trying to implement some custom types, yet my IDE and MyPy don't recognise it properly.

This is the code snippet:

```py
from typing import Union


class MissingType(type):
    ...


MISSING = MissingType


class APINullable(type):
    @staticmethod
    def __class_getitem__(item):
        print(f"Getting Union[{item.__name__}, MISSING]")
        return Union[item, MISSING]


lol: APINullable[str] = MISSING
lol2: APINullable[str] = "test"
lol3: APINullable[str] = 123

for i in (lol, lol2, lol3):
    print(i, type(i), i is MISSING)
```

Which has this output:

```
Getting Union[str, MISSING]
Getting Union[str, MISSING]
Getting Union[str, MISSING]
<class '__main__.MissingType'> <class 'type'> True
test <class 'str'> False
123 <class 'int'> False
```

And thats totally expected and right, but for some reason Pycharm, VSCode *(w Pylance)* and MyPy don't recognise this. This is the MyPy output:

```js
test.py:18: error: "APINullable" expects no type arguments, but 1 given
test.py:18: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[MissingType]", variable has type "APINullable")
test.py:19: error: "APINullable" expects no type arguments, but 1 given
test.py:19: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "APINullable")
test.py:20: error: "APINullable" expects no type arguments, but 1 given
test.py:20: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "APINullable")
Found 6 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

*(Just in case if this is a bug, and there is nothing wrong with my implementation I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/887))*

Comment: This is working fine with me on Pycharm. Do you have any specific case where it fails?

Comment: There is a similar issue here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2425
You can basically solve this by using TypeVar and making APINullable generic

Comment: Please be aware that a ``class`` statement already defines a type. Deriving a class from ``type`` defines a *meta*-type whose *instances* are types. This is usually not what one should do, and likely not what you wanted to do either as implied by ``lol3: APINullable[str] = "test"``. This says the type of ``"test"`` is the *meta*type ``APINullable``, i.e. ``lol3()[0]`` (*instantiating* then indexing) would be valid.